# Copy an array into the middle of a larger array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've searched through the answers here, but I can only find this question answered for other languages.

So I have 2 Uint8 typed arrays.

```
var arr1 = [0,0,0];
var arr2 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
```

I want to replace the contents of arr2 with arr1 starting at the 4th position. So that arr2 will be:

```
arr2 = [0,1,2,0,0,0,6,7,8,9];
```

If I wasn't trying to do this in the middle of the array I could use [set like this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/set):

```
arr2.set(arr1);
```

And I would get:

```
arr2 = [0,0,0,4,5,6,7,8,9];
```

I know I can loop through the arr2 and individually copy the values, but performance wise this is very slow compared to set (and performance matters to me because it's copying an entire array of canvas img data 24 times a second).

Is there any function that can copy into the middle of an array, but with the performance of set?

Comment: is the 4th position a random position or will it always be the 4th position?

Comment: @Sagivb.g It's random based on the input data, but I'll always have a variable ahead of time to reference the position.

Comment: Maybe set itself has the same performance rate!

Comment: @Eineki, no sorry I tested that several times. Set's performance beats looping over the array hands down. It's nearly 300% faster on large arrays.

Comment: @YAHsaves maybe I explained myself badly. I was saying that you would have used the set method itself, since it has the optional offset parameter used to do exactly what you needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`typedarray.set(array[, offset])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/set) offset.

> **offset *Optional***
>
> The offset into the target array at which to begin
>   writing values from the source array. If you omit this value, 0 is
>   assumed (that is, the source array will overwrite values in the target
>   array starting at index 0).

```js
const arr1 = new Uint8Array([0,0,0]);
const arr2 = new Uint8Array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]);

arr2.set(arr1, 4);

console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: @OriDrori, happy new year!

Comment: @NinaScholz - happy new year :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method with the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```js
const shim = (source, index, target) => [
  ...source.slice(0, index),
  ...target,
  ...source.slice(index)
]

var arr1 = [0,0,0];
var arr2 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

const newArr = shim(arr2, 3, arr1);
console.log(newArr);
```

`.slice` will not mutate the array and will return a new shallow copy of it (unlike [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using typed array. Don't you can use the offset of the set method?

```
arr2.set(arr1, 3)
```

To overwrite from the 4th element of the target array.
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/set

To me it does just what you need, if I understand your question.